# Correct way to show ViewController from push notification when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to show a view controller when my app is open from a push notification, but it's crashing because I'm trying to get the UINavigationController, which is not still initialized in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

My code is this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let profileController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileViewControllerIdentifier") as! ProfileViewController

        let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.pushViewController(profileController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to show a ViewController when coming from a push notification when the app was closed?

Comment: can you show us what are you getting when you print self.window?.rootViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found what the problem was, I was accessing some data from the navigationcontroller, which was not still initialized.

Answer (score 0):

So, the main reason I see is that your `rootViewController` is not a `UINavigationController`. It could be because:

1. `rootViewController` is another `UIViewController`
2. The `UINavigationController` is not set as the `rootViewController` in your storyboard.

So without any print about what are you getting from `self.window?.rootViewController` I think you can run this line to see if you can get your `UINavigationController`:

```
var myNav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNavIdHere") as? UINavigationController
```

just make sure to add an ID to your UINavigationController. (this is just to check you can reach your NavController)